# CSS issue: a:hover not working with IE (css Ninja needed)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, dhtml

Why does IE not change the background color on my site for tabs a:hover but does so in Firefox/Chrome/Safari correctly?

What can I do to make it work in IE 6+?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabbernav">
<li class="tabberactive"><a title="All" href="javascript:void(null);">All</a></li>
<li class=""><a>Tab1<span class="tabTotal"> (0)</span></a></li>
<li class=""><a>Tab2<span class="tabTotal"> (2)</span></a></li>
<li class=""><a>Tab3<span class="tabTotal"> (1)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.tabbernav li a:hover {background:#fdfdfd; border: 1px solid #555; border-bottom: none; color:#3366a9; cursor: pointer}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when I view your source, I don't see the mentioned items as a list. I see it as div's with h2 tags.

Comment: You also don't appear to have any links in there either for those elements. So, those reasons combined are enough to make it not work correctly.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include code

Comment: Just an idea...What happens if you change .document. to .window. in the inline js?

Comment: @Anthony, changing .document to .window has no effect

Comment: I took apart that stylesheet element by element and I think I've got it. It appears that IE needs an href on the link to recognize it properly. I've updated my post below accordingly. Hope that does it!

Comment: @TimJK - You sure love ninja...

Comment: I was facing same kind of problem in IE.My code worked fine in chrome and FF. Adding <code>< !doctype html></code>in html page worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing I'd do is double check that the order of the psuedo selectors is correct.

It should be-

```
a:link {color:#FF0000} /* unvisited link */  
a:visited {color:#00FF00} /* visited link */  
a:hover {color:#FF00FF} /* mouse over link */  
a:active {color:#0000FF} /* selected link */
```

The only specific IE hover issue I remember relates to non-link elements so I don't think that is your issue. http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762 - Just in case.

If that doesn't answer your question do you mind posting the related block of css?

---

GAH- That was a hard one!

It looks like IE is breaking because the links don't have an associated Href element. Fix that and you should be fine.

--Breaking News - I may be an idiot- That was the last thing I changed on my test page and that fixed it but when I put it all back together it broke everywhere... so take what I just posted with a grain of salt. I'm backing up to see what happened.

Comment: Thanks! - I can't get my test file to work on any browser now even though I've reverted back to the original code. I think there was black magic at work here. Hopefully all is well now and if i just burn the test file we'll all be ok.

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer for hover on button elements in IE7 everywhere; and everyone has the same "use javascript" answer I don't like. Adding the HTML 4.0 DTD worked like a champ. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You should place `href=""` attribute in `<a>` tag.

This will work fine.

Also use the `<!doctype html>` tag at the top of the page. Now everything will be fine.

Comment: In my case, I had a `:hover` on a `<div>` element. Using the `<!doctype html>` declaration was enough to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
display: block;
position: relative;
```

to your css `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a simple fix! Use  background-color:#fffffe if changing background-color:#fff to background:#fff does not work.

http://haslayout.net/css/Hover-White-Background-Ignore-Bug

Answer (score 1):

Add blow tag to `<head>` for fix it.

for IE9

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

for IE10

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

Comment: This fixed my issue on IE11, I used the IE=10. Did not break Firefox or Chrome with that line left in.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE 7 fixed the hover problem on elements other than `<a>`, but haven't tested.

To make up for IE 6's lack of support for the :hover selector, you just need to use javascript to get the same effect. Set an onMouseOver event that applies the class you want. :D

Comment: This is being applied to a:hover, I believe you're referring to IE 7+ ability to apply :hover to more than just hyperlinks. I don't need to apply this to anything EXCEPT hyperlinks, so I don't think your answer applies

Comment: IE6 never had a problem with hovering on <a> elements. Just all of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS looks to be valid.

Try adding an '!important' to your a:hover, and also try altering other styles in the definition. You may have some other style overriding that particular a:hover style via cascade.

Firebug in FF may show you some conflicting styles being inherited (although in IE6 you're on your own of course), but you should make sure you are not conflicting. a:hover works fine in IE6 as you and others in the question are aweare of

Also, put semicolons and newlines after your declarations you filthy heathen!

Comment: The strange think is that literally no matter what I put inside "ul.tabbernav li a:hover", IE 6+ doesn't recognize it but other browsers do. So if I change the FONT, or TEXT-DECORATION, etc... IE 6+ doesn't do it but all other browser do. With that being the case, !important is obviously not working. It's as thought IE 6+ does even notice I've declared anything inside "ul.tabbernav li a:hover"

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a javascript error (Invalid property Value) in IE at line ~852:

```
document.getElementById('panel-hlisting-all').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

where color has the value "#ffff100".

Could this be the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of it now - why not use Jquery to do it? with just a FEW lines of code you will have it done.

First, download Jquery from [www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com). Then, you should properly link it to your file, on the head of your HTML:

```
<script src="url_to_your_jquery_file_here"></script>
```

Then, add another part of Javascript below this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("li a").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).css("color", "#3366a9");
          }, 
          function () {
            $(this).css("color","#838383");
          }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, much more than 1 line of code :( but it whould work anyway.

Comment: I would set and remove a `.hover` class instead, and do the styling in css by targetting `ul.tabbernav li a:hover, ul.tabbernav li a.hover { ... }`. If you update the answer to do so you get +1. :p

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution I found. In my case, the bug was determined by the **Google Translator**. I removed it in IE and Opera (where it causes other errors) and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page. It will fix the problem and other problems that may arise.

Answer (score 0):

Hover element in quirk mode in IE doesn't work. Alternative is set via script-event (without jquery) of html element:

```
<a onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" >  My link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add following line to the top of your html file, it works for me in is 9 and up:

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following line to the top of your html file, it works for me in ie 9:

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an expression in your CSS. I use this technique, i developed to a client's site.

Just put it on the END of your CSS, since Webkit browsers won't read anything below it.

```
* html * { color: expression( (function(who){ if(!who.MXPC){
 who.MXPC = '1';
 if(who.nodeName != 'A'){
  who.onmouseenter=function(){ who.className += ' hover'};
  who.onmouseleave=function(){ who.className = who.className.replace(' hover','')}; }
 (who==who.parentNode.firstChild) ? who.className += ' first-child' : '' ;
} } )(this) , 'auto') }
```